# Any way to segregate ports on a Mellanox Infiniband switch?

Tags: linux, networking, infiniband

I currently have two infiniband IPoIB networks across multiple unmanaged switches (along with some PCs running as the subnet managers) with multiple Linux nodes attached with Infiniband adapters.

There is an SX6036 switch in-house that I'd like to use to consolidate the SMs, networks and connections however one IPoIB network runs in a DMZ, while the other IPoIB network runs on the LAN. I need to keep these two networks segregated (along with ACLS on the servers) for security compliance.

Is there a way to group a range of ports into one IPoIB subnet (similar to ethernet VLAN) and group another range of ports into a different subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use P_Keys to partition an InfiniBand network into multiple virtual networks. The following [guide](https://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-1925) can help.